# syntax error in every python scripts SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

```
  File "account_creator.py", line 63
    username = f"{first_name}_{last_name}{random.randint(1000, 9999)}"
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

every script i run gives this error

Comment: You are running an old Python version that does not support f-strings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and **ask a question**. That said, yes; this error occurs because f-strings are not supported. In older versions of Python, the compiler will just see `username`, `=`, `f` (like, a variable named `f`) and an ordinary string.

Comment: F-strings can be use only in Python 3.6 or more :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a newer version of Python. Install a version of python 3.6 or newer, then your problem should be solved!